# What purposes can the tilde, '~', be used for in informal writing?

Tags: punctuation

In informal messages such as emails between friends, I often see the tilde character after people's names, as if 'calling' them:

> 민정아 ~

But it seems like it can be put after many other sentences:

> 내일 다시 만나 ~

What does the ~ sign mean? Does it indicate a certain sound or tone of voice? When is it appropriate  to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tilde is used to make the sentence more friendly. Fyi, check this:

http://www.koreanwikiproject.com/wiki/Internet_and_text_messaging